# Need .htaccess Rewrite Rule To Remove Trailing <br%20/>

Tags: regular-expression, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have links that for some reason have a trailing `<br%20/>` and I don't know where they are coming from to try and fix them.  So I need a general rewrite rule to remove them so the links won't show up as 404's.

I am using amazon-linux-ami/2014.09 and my Apache is Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon).

This is the original link: `abc.com/pages.php?pageid=265<br%20/>`

Here is what I have tried:

#### Strip <br /> from CMS Page Endings - `/pages.php?pageid=265<br%20/>`

RewriteRule `^/pages\.php\?pageid=([0-9]+)(<br\s/>)?$ /pages.php?pageid=$1? [R=301,L]`

When this rule is used I get this instead.

`abc.com/pages.php?pageid=265<br />`

What I want is `abc.com/pages.php?pageid=265` with the option for the `pageid` to be any number.

Since I don't have the reputation I removed the `http://www`.

Comment: Where is the Value for `pageid` being stored?  `%20` is the URL Encoding Code fore the character `space`, so the question I must ask is why you are storing `<br />` in your pageid column that should be typed to store int's?

Comment: G-Man - thanks for changing the formatting.  This is my first post so please tell me how you changed it so I won't make the same mistake again.

Comment: You're covering up a symptom instead of fixing the actual problem.  Instead of trying to fix a symptom by writing a rewrite rule fix the page id's to be ints so that the database, i presume, doesn't store the HTML tag for a break

Comment: Hi eyoung100,I am not storing the <br /> in the pageid.  That's the way the link is coming in from the internet and I am just trying to fix the link.  The value for pageid is provided in the url so it isn't being stored except in the DB that has the content.

Comment: I am  not covering a symptom because these are links that are being accessed external to our site.  Consequently, they aren't in the DB for me to change them.

Comment: What generates your page Id?, and I disagree, as pages.php takes pageid as an argument in order to generate the page, therefore the pageid must be being created by your CMS.

Comment: See [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) on the Wordpress Codex even though the CMS may not be Wordpress.  The page_id must be stored in the DB in order for this to work, therefore I postulate that you or your CMS is inadvertently adding the `<br />` tag to your page ids when storing them or your query to retrieve them is appending the tag.  If the link is external, you must statically code each link to not include the tag.

Comment: @sharingsun: Look at the bottom of your question. At the left it lists some words, which are links; the first one is probably “share”. To the right it shows your name and gravatar, and says when you asked the question. In the middle it shows the name and gravatar of the most recent person to edit the post (currently that’s me) and above that it says when that edit occurred. Click on that “edited (date/time)” text, and it will take you to the revision history. Hint: since Stack Exchange accepts minimal HTML in posts, you need to use `&lt;` (less than) if you want to actually show a `<` in text.